# При переопределении глобальных переменных в функци ошибка: local variable referenced before assigment

Tags: python, global-variables

После определение переменных `health` и остальных  как глобальные, при переопределении их в функции `Upgrade()` выдает ошибку:

> local variable 'health' referenced before assigment

```
global health
global basic_damage
global basic_armor
global basic_true_strike
global choice
health=100
basic_damage=10
basic_armor=5
basic_true_strike=50
choice=0
def Upgrade():
   health+=5
   basic_damage+=5
   basic_armor+=5
   basic_true_strike+=5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменные, определённые в корне модуля, к примеру `health`, и так являются глобальными.
Как только Вы запускаете функцию, она создаёт для себя локальную область видимости.
Как раз в функции Вы и должны указать, что хотите использовать глобальную переменную с помощью инструкции `global`.

Вот пример:

```py
health = 100
basic_damage = 10
basic_armor = 5
basic_true_strike = 50
choice = 0


def upgrade():
    global health, basic_damage, basic_armor, basic_true_strike

    health += 5
    basic_damage += 5
    basic_armor += 5
    basic_true_strike += 5

upgrade()

print(health, basic_damage, basic_armor, basic_true_strike)
```

*stdout:*

```html
105 15 10 55
```

Comment: Спасибо большое